# Order columns in MLflow ui

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlflow

I am using the MLflow UI to track machine learning experiments.
I want to be able to sort the position of the columns (that seems to be in alphabetical order by default).

###### My use case.

I log different metrics with `mlflow.log_metric()`.
Let's say I track `AUC` and `logloss` (and possibly many others) but I am mainly interested in the logloss. I want it to be in the first position in the UI.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Couldn't find a solution either. A workaround is to add a prefix "." to the variables you want at the top.